# Stop CSS background property from moving background on resize

Tags: html, css, properties, background

I recently found the problem on a recent question I asked here which was related to what I thought was a Chrome or Safari webkit bug, or maybe something inside my style.css. However, I noticed after a while that my background was slightly moving on resize, and I concluded that when it moved towards the right, a left white border didn't show up from top to bottom on the left side of the screen, but when the background picture moved towards the right hand side then a 2px white border showed up on the left right side. How do I stop the border from moving.

MY CSS:

```
html { 
    background: url(/assets/fotball.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hB2h6/ there you go, on the top of the page you can see a white border randomly appearing and if you go to the link: http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Plain-Black-Wallpaper.png You can see there is none. If you can't see the white border, try resizing the JSfiddle page. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background: url(/assets/fotball.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
```

Comment: in the fiddle it fills up all space without showing the border, may be in ur page with other controls (code) the layout changes. can u provide some screenshot or link to show the issue visually?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this: [**jsFiddle Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/hB2h6/5/)

```
html { 
    background: url(/assets/fotball.jpg) repeat center top fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:;
}
```

When you use `background-size: cover;`, it makes no difference to use `background:no-repeat` or `background:repeat`. So in this case you can use `repeat` to solve your problem.

Comment: It did remove the white border, but it now added a little green line because the football field is green. Instead of the white line. Better, but still not perfect. :( Any more ideas?

Comment: @MFCS Can you upload your background image somewhere so i can see what's happening?

Comment: Here the picture I am testing with: http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/piyato/piyato1110/piyato111000037/10786305-football-on-grass-background.jpg

Comment: http://www.colourbox.com/preview/3275168-587980-pine-tree-close-up-and-other-trees-at-background.jpg this doesn't work. Try it yourself.
**EDIT** then what is the problem, if it works in the fiddle but not in my CHrome!!!! :@

Comment: @MFCS I don't know maybe you have some other codes that interfere with this code and cause the problem. Also i think you can solve this by set a `background-color` similar to your image color which you can't see the difference.